# Is there a term for the first moment of mass?

Tags: mass, terminology, moment-of-inertia, moment

If a stationary object has a rest-mass of say $2.0$kg and is located a distance $3.0$m from a particular point (of which it is stationary relative to).

Is there some term to describe the moment of it's mass?

Mass moment = mass x perpendicular distance = $6.0$kg.m

Note: I'm not referring to momentum.

Also: Wiki says that moment of inertia is mass x distance squared.

I'm looking for mass x distance.

Comment: The "first moment of mass" is essentially the [centre of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass). The second is the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on By Symmetry's comment: if you have some mass (density) distribution, $\rho({\bf \vec x})$, to which a force, ${\bf \vec F}$ is applied at the origin, then:

The zeroth (scalar) moment tells you the total mass:

$$ m = \int{\rho({\bf \vec x})d^3x} $$

so the acceleration is:

$$ {\bf \vec a} = {\bf \vec F} / m$$

The 1st (vector) moment tells you the center of mass position (times the mass):

$$ {\bf \vec{x}}_0/m = \int{\rho({\bf \vec x}){\bf \vec{x}}d^3x} $$

Hence you can compute the torque on the mass distribution:

$$ {\bf \vec{\tau}} = {\bf \vec x}_0 {\bf \times \vec{F}}$$

As you pointed out, the 2nd (tensor) moment is the inertia tensor:

$$ {\bf \overleftrightarrow I} = \int{\rho({\bf \vec x})([{\bf \vec x \vec \cdot x)I}_2-({\bf \vec x \otimes \vec x)}] d^3x}$$

relates the torque and angular acceleration:

$${\bf \vec{\tau}}={\bf \overleftrightarrow I}\dot{\bf \omega} $$

Comment: Bold face *and* and arrow?   I suppose you're a suspenders *and* a belt kind of guy.   :-)

Comment: @garyp More like lemon and cream.